# How to create a canvas with image of video frame

Tags: video, canvas, screenshot, drawimage

I'm hoping to use canvas' drawimage to create what is effectively a screenshot of the video tag (currently playing). I know this is possible, but I'm not clear on how.

Source of inspiration:
http://www.craftymind.com/2010/04/20/blowing-up-html5-video-and-mapping-it-into-3d-space/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally you just do `drawImage(videoTagReference, 0, 0)`

That will draw the `<video>` onto the canvas at the current frame.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm trying, but there must be some other bug. I'm going to work on it some more and report back here when I figure out what it is.

Comment: Oh, duh, visibility / opacity wasn't being unset from the canvas when it was with the video.